# Workaround for CSS "top" property in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: css

Microsoft Edge ignores CSS "top" properties with relative values. Example:

```css
.mycontent
{
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
 -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 max-height: 510px;
 max-width: 594px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background : #FFFFFF;
 background : rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
 border-style : Solid;
 border-color : #000000;
 border-color : rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
 border-width : 1px;
 border-radius : 35px;
 -moz-border-radius : 35px;
 -webkit-border-radius : 35px;
}
```

Is there a workaround for using it in Microsoft Edge?

Comment: can @Nico can you please provide jsfiddle because Run code snippet was not showing what you want exactly and when i tried your css it showing a black line in the top of browser. I am not getting what you want exactly

Comment: I just created a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sozon2d5/

Comment: I just want to center a div horizontally and vertically.

Comment: which browser you are using becausse in chrome it was showing perfectly

Comment: I tried it in Chrome and Edge. Chrome works perfectly for me, too.

Comment: i checked in edge it was perfect for me in which version you are checking 10,9,8,7...

Comment: It´s Edge 25.10586.0.0

Comment: mine even less than that edge 20

Comment: Thanks for your help, as you can see, I found a solution by myself...

Answer (score 1):

I used padding-top to set its position instead of "top".
It works perfect

```
.mycontent {

top: 50%;

}
```

to

```
.mycontent {

padding-top: 100px; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found it out by myself, the best (and working way) is using jQuery.
Here the running code.

```js
$(window).resize(function(){

 $('.mycontent').css({
  position:'absolute',
  left: ($(window).width() - $('.mycontent').outerWidth())/2,
  top: ($(window).height() - $('.mycontent').outerHeight())/2
 });

});

$(document).ready(function(){
    // To initially run the function:
$(window).resize();
});
```

```css
.mycontent
{
 
 max-height: 510px;
 max-width: 594px;
 
 background : #FFFFFF;
 background : rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
 border-style : Solid;
 border-color : #000000;
 border-color : rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
 border-width : 1px;
 border-radius : 35px;
 -moz-border-radius : 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius : 10px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<title>Seite im Aufbau</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">


</head>

<body>

<div class="mycontent">

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  
  
</div>



</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a Edge bug/quirk. I fixed that by setting `position: relative` on parent element and `position: absolute` on the child you want to center vertically.

Answer (score -1):

Yee that is annoying. I have same problem. Solved with flex.
For that container give:

```
align-self:center
```

Of course parent need:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```